# How to add value into array overtime user click on next button in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

When the user click the next button, it generate random number and I would like to store the number into the array. My array is storing the last number only. Should I initialize the array outside the 'next' function? Moreover, I would like the 'back button' to read the array from the last in number. Please advise.

```
- (IBAction)Next:(id)sender {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //generate random number - result is a range of 0-10   
    int randomnumber = (arc4random() % 10);

   // Add the random number into array
   [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomnumber]];

    // easy way to look what is now in the array
        NSLog([myArray description]);

     NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File_no_%d", randomnumber +1];

    //render a complete file-path out of our filename, the main-bundle and the file-  extension

    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"txt"];

    //fetch the text content from that file

    NSString *myText= [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:nil];

    //hand that text over to our textview

    TextView.text=myText;
}

- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {

    NSNumber *last_array_num = [myArray objectAtIndex:myArray.count - 1];

   // read the file name based on the last number in array

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File_no_%d", last_array_num ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are initializing the array within the Next method as well as adding to it?  If so, the array needs to be initialized outside that method, and just once.  This keeps your data intact, otherwise it is overwritten when you initialize it the next time.

You are adding to the array just fine, so that doesn't need to change at all.  As for reading the number in your Back method, you simply need to have the following line of code:

EDIT: this is the code you would use to get the results you want from your array. Also, the formal approach is not to start with capital letters in your code unless it defines a class (like NSString).  For methods, like this, you should use something like `- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender` instead.  It's not a big deal at all and your code will work fine, but it's just etiquette and keeps your code a bit less confusing in the long run.  I have a feeling someone might say something about it later, so I'm just letting you know ahead of time.  Anyway, here is the code you want

SECOND EDIT: Like you were thinking, you should make a variable that can be read from in the code.  In your header file, add this

```
int arrayCount;
```

In your code, once myArray is created, set arrayCount

```
arrayCount = [myArray count];
```

This should also be done if add or remove any objects from the array.

Then in your action method, you can call the files

```
- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"File_no_%d", [[myArray objectAtIndex:arrayCount - 1] intValue]];

    // make sure you aren't going beyond the bounds of the array;
    if (arrayCount > 1) {
        // decrease the count of the arrayCount;
        arrayCount--;
    }
}
```

Using this should allow you to move backwards in your array one step each time you click the button.  Again, if this isn't what you are looking for, just let me know and we will get to the bottom of it

Comment: I kinda confused where to declare it in outside. Is this like below?

Comment: - (void) initArray
{
    //hold the array number up to 10

    myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
}

or

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
    myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
}

Comment: Initializing it in your `viewDidLoad` method is the best choice.  To make sure it is retained properly, you should have something like this: `- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10]; }`

Comment: It works for next button. It adds the number into array. However, for back button, it only reads the last number. No matter how many times I click the bank button, it only reads the last number in array.

Comment: I thought you wanted to read only the last number inserted into the array.  What exactly do you want to read when you click Back?  Once we know that, it'll be easier to advice you how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I want it read the number from last in and first out. For example if the array has (2,5,7,9,3) then the back button should read backward (3,9,7,5,2).

I also add below code in 'back' function to prevent crash if the array is blank. However, I have warning on '*count'. It said 'incompatible integer to pointer conversion intiliazing NSUInteger.

 NSUInteger *count = [myArray count] ;

    if (count == nil){

       // NSLog(@"array blank");

    }

    else

    {

    //do read the file

}

Comment: I understand what you mean now.  I'm going to edit my original answer with how you would do that.  It will be easier to read it there rather than in a comment

Comment: NSUInteger *count = [myArray count]  it should be like this NSUInteger count = [myArray count]

Comment: @Slev,
Hmmm.. let me rephrase it again. When the user click back button, it should return 'File_no_2'. If the user click back button again, then it should return 'File_no_7'. However, if the user click on next button, it should add the new number into the array. So the array should be {0,5,7,2,X} where x is the new number.
Thanks

Comment: @Slev, I think in my opinion, I should pass the last index of array as global variable outside that function. So when the user click the back button again, the code should get that global variable and minus 1 and retrieve the correct array index. But I don't know how to do it in xcode.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Again, I'm going to edit this in the original answer so it's easier to read.  Hopefully this will give you what you want

Comment: @Slev, Bingo it works.....until the last first index (0) and it crashed. I need to add if the array count = nil or array index =0 and it should do nothing.


 NSUInteger *count = [myArray count] ;

    if (count == nil) {
       // do nothing
    }
    else
    {
      //your code here
}

Comment: The `if (arrayCount > 0)` part should make sure you don't decrease below zero...........oh, oh.  I'm so sorry.  I forgot that when we call [myArray objectAtIndex:...], we are using arrayCount - 1.  Let me change that so it won't crash.  My apologies.  It should be fine after I switch the parameters to `if (arrayCount > 1)`

Comment: Jeez...I can't even figure that things out. I'll keep trying like arrayCount==0. I am so noob. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: My pleasure.  I'm sure you'll be coding like a beast soon.  You learn a bunch of tricks on the way.  NSLog statements help a lot to figure out what's crashing and when.  But I'm really glad it's working for you now and doing what you want